# Javascript behavior with numbers

Tags: javascript, browser

I tried to compare 10 and 010 `as 10 == 010`, But I got result as `false`.

Then I tried to print/alert following values,

```
10 result 10
010 result 8
12 result 12
012 result 10
100 result 100
0100 result 64
65 result 65
065 result 53
99 result 99
099 result 99
196 result 196
0196 result 196
```

Same kind of results for negative numbers too,

```
-99 result -99
-099 result -99
-32 result -32
-032 result -26
-196 result -196
-0196 result -196
-66 result -66
-066 result -54
```

***More Info***

> from (+/-)078 to (+/-)099 results are as correct.

Ex:

```
78 result 78
078 result 78
-87 result -87
-087 result -87
```

***Same behavior in Chrome, FireFox, IE.***

I'm wondering why this strange behavior? Is it JS bug or JS special feature. 
Can someone explain why this is so.

Thanks in advance.

*Please comment if you need any details.*

Comment: Please show the actual JS involved. But note that a leading zero tells it you want the number to be treated as octal. (And a leading `0x` as in `0x123` tells it the number is hexadecimal.)

Comment: It's a feature. Numbers starting with 0 are treated as octal, while starting with 0x are treated as hexadecimal.

Comment: Like commented above they are seen as octal. You can also test it by doing `10 == 012` (true) because like you found above, 012 octal is 10 in decimal. This is also why it is very important to set the radix in [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and it is even stated in the description