# Why in JavaScript does 10 === 010 result in false

Tags: javascript

Why is it in JavaScript that the following results in false:

```
10 === 000000010 (false)
```

But this results in true:

```
010 === 000000010 (true)
```

In all cases the left and right are both 10, they should all result in true shouldn't they?

Comment: `1 == 01` and `1 === 01` are both true in my browser (Chrome)

Comment: I tried in firefox console, but  1 == 01 (true) 1 === 01 (true)

Comment: Are you sure you didn't actually try `10 == 010`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Octal

Comment: `010` is octal, it's equivalent to `8`.

Comment: The question probably should be "Why is `10 != 010` ?"

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [Javascript behavior with numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26628507/javascript-behavior-with-numbers), which has been closed as a duplicate of [In JavaScript, eval(010) returns 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718102/in-javascript-eval010-returns-8). I'm voting to close this question as a dupe of the latter.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

JavaScript numbers beginning with leading `0`s followed by any of the digits `01234567` are [octal (base 8)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) rather than in decimal (base 10).

You can see this in an example like this:

```
10 === 010 // false
8 === 010 // true
```

Note that if there is an `8` or `9` digit, it is not a valid octal number and thus will be interpreted as a decimal number:

```
89 === 089 // true
```

Note that octal literals don't work in strict mode:

```
(function(){ "use strict"; return 010 === 10; })()
// SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.
```

This is described in section [B.1.1 of the JavaScript specification](https://es5.github.io/#B.1.1) as non-normative behavior for compatibility with older versions of ECMAScript. An octal integer literal is defined as follows:

```
OctalIntegerLiteral ::
    0 OctalDigit
    OctalIntegerLiteral OctalDigit

OctalDigit :: one of
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: "if there is an 8 or 9 digit, it ... will be interpreted as a decimal number" Javascript _would_ do that, wouldn't it.

Answer (score 8):

Your current example not-withstanding, numbers prefixed with a `0` that only contain the digits 0-7 are interpreted as [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal). A better example would be

```
123 == 0123 // nope
```

because `0123` in base 10 is `83`.

---

To bring it inline with your updated example

```
parseInt(10, 10) // 10
parseInt(000000010, 10) // 8
parseInt(010, 10) // 8
```

Comment: Just nitpicking, the first arg to parseInt should be a string, it could affect the result.

Comment: @K3N From the docs ~ *"The value to parse. If string is not a string, then it is converted to one. Leading whitespace in the string is ignored."*. I think it's safe and was mainly just to show OP what each value is in base10

Comment: @Phil try running sure, it cast them, but if you provided those numbers as string the result would be different (ie. `parseInt("000000010", 10) // = 10` just sayin

Comment: @K3N good thing I didn't pass in strings then

Comment: @K3N: But `parseInt(010, 10)` does the same as `parseInt(8, 10)`. You can try `parseInt(010, 10)` vs `parseInt("010", 10)` to show a difference, but using `parseInt` just doesn't make sense in a question about the values of literals.